# First-chance exception at 0x00998876 in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I am writing a hangman game. I cannot proceed with debugging because I do not understand this error:

> First-chance exception at 0x00998876 in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x00000000. Unhandled exception at
>   0x00998876 in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0x00000000.

This is where the error is being generated:

```
void Player::getWords()
{ 
  ifstream WordBank;
  int index=0;
  WordBank.open("C:\\WordBank\\words.txt");

  if(WordBank)
  {
      for(index=0;index<100;index++)
      {     
           WordBank>>Words1[index];     
      }
      WordBank.close();
  }
  else
  {
      cout<<"There was an error."<<endl;
  } 
}
```

The Words array is declared as a member variable.

Here is my code. I am not yet sure how formatting words and I am trying to finish this program.

```
class Player
{   public:
    string fName;
     string lName;
     int DOB;
     string username;
     int SS4;
     string email;
     int won;
     int lost;
     const int static  WordSIZE=15;
     int const static totalWORDS=100;
     string static Letters[WordSIZE];
     string static  Words1[totalWORDS];
     char static   Copy[WordSIZE];
     char static Guess[WordSIZE];
     int index;
     int word;
     int size;
     int isComing;//I need function to initialize these.
     char letter;
     bool correct;//I need a function to initialize these.
     string Word1;
public:
    Player(string,string,int,string,int,string);
    void getWords();
    void boardSetup();
    void playGame();
    void deathBed(int);



};

Player::Player(string first,string last,int birth, string nicname,int SS,string mail)
{
 fName=first;
 lName=last;
 DOB=birth;
 username=nicname;
 SS4=SS;
 email=mail;
 isComing=0;
 correct=true;
}
    const int static  WordSIZE=15;
     int const static totalWORDS=100;
  string Player::  Words1[totalWORDS]; 
    char Player::   Copy[WordSIZE];
     char Player:: Guess[WordSIZE];
      string Player:: Letters[WordSIZE];
 void Player::getWords()
{ 





  ifstream WordBank;
  int index=0;
    WordBank.open("C:\\WordBank\\words.txt");


    if(WordBank)
    {
         while(WordBank>>Words1[index])
         {
           index++;
         }
     WordBank.close();
    }
    else
        {
          cout<<"There was an error."<<endl;
        }

}


    /*string *words2;
    words2=new  string[100];
  ifstream WordBank;
  int index;
    WordBank.open("C:\\WordBank\\words.txt");


    if(WordBank)
    {
       for(index=0;(WordBank>>words2[index]);index++)
        {



        }
    WordBank.close();
    }
    else
        {
          cout<<"There was an error."<<endl;
        }
    delete [] words2;
   words2=0;
}*/

void Player::boardSetup()
{
    unsigned seed =time(0);
    srand(seed);
    word=rand()%100;
    Words1[word]=Word1;
    strcpy_s(Copy,Word1.c_str());

    size=strlen(Word1.c_str());
    for(index=0;index<size;index++)
    {
        Guess[index]='-';
        cout<<Guess[index]<<endl;
    }


}







}

void Player::playGame()
{
    while(isComing!=7)
    {
        deathBed(isComing);
        cout<<Guess<<endl;
        cout<< "Please guess a letter."<<endl;// or press 0 to go to the main screen for help
        cin>>letter;
        letter=toupper(letter);

            for (index=0;index<size;index++)
        {
            if(Copy[index]==letter)
            {
               cout<<"Nice Job"<<endl; //add the ability to see the word
               Guess[index]=letter;
               cout<<Guess[index]<<endl;

            }
            else  if(strcmp(Word1.c_str(),Guess)==0)
              {
                  cout<<"You WIN!!!"<<endl;
                  return;
              }

            else if (correct=false)
            {
                cout<<"Please,Try again"<<endl;
                isComing++;
            }
        }

    }
     void deathBed(int isComing);

     cout<<"The word is"<<Words1[word]<<"."<<endl;

     //draw a big red noose. call a function for it.

}


struct userInfo
{
    string FName;
    string LName;
    int dob;
    string Username;
    int ss4;
    string Email;
};

userInfo getUserInfo();


int main()
{ 
  userInfo i; 
     i=getUserInfo();
 Player player1(i.FName,i.LName,i.dob,i.Username,i.ss4,i.Email);
 player1.getWords();
 player1.boardSetup();
 player1.playGame();

    return 0;
}

userInfo getUserInfo()
{
    userInfo info;

    cout<<"What is your first name?"<<endl;
    cin>> info.FName;
    cout<<"What is your last name?"<<endl;
    cin>>info.LName;
    cout<<"What is your date of birth"<<endl;
    cin>>info.dob;
    cout<<"Please enter a user name."<<endl;
    cin>>info.Username;
    cout<<"Please enter the last four digits of your Social Security number."<<endl;
    cin>>info.ss4;
    cout<<"Please enter your email address."<<endl;
    cin>>info.Email;

    return info;
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you are trying to write to a pointer that is NULL.

Comment: Can you show the declaration for Words1?

Comment: Doesn't your debugger show you exactly which line is writing through a null pointer?

Comment: Or maybe is Player itself NULL?

Comment: He's looking at the Output window instead of the debugger.

Comment: What kind of array is `Words1` and is the `>>` operator defined on that type?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us your *testcase*, but the debug error clearly shows that you're writing through a null pointer (probably at `Words1`).

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses. I am not using any pointers. I know that arrays are constant pointers to a memory address, but I have not declared any pointers for dynamic memory allocation.( What is a test case? I am looking at the output window. I have only been programming for about 3 months. I am not sure how to read or what is the debugger window.) I did research the issue and most said that I am trying to dereferance a null pointer. That would mean that I am using a pointer that points to 'null' or nothing.

Comment: string static  Words1[totalWORDS];

Comment: That is my class declaration or Words1[totalWords].

Comment: I know you guys are busy can you at least point me in a good direction.

Comment: We really can not help more without your help. You need to post more of your code since we have to guess with what you posted. Please edit your original question.

Comment: I do not like the use of so many static variables and the mix of c strings and c++ strings but all of that may not be related to the problem. I will attempt to look at this later. I have to get back to work.

Comment: @user3062441: What is a testcase? [Oh, nothing ...](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)

Comment: `I know that arrays are constant pointers to a memory address` Um, no. Arrays are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code on Visual Studio 2012. You have a problem with your boardSetup() function that is preventing the game from being played. Your assignment for Word1 is the wrong way. I mean you should have

```
Word1=Words1[word];
```

Instead of

```
Words1[word]=Word1;
```

After this the program runs and you can play. However when you win it does not say so. It just keeps asking for more letters. I will leave that exercise up to you. I did not see any crash, null pointer access or bad_alloc (although those were not expected since you are not using pointers).